# Read file line by line with bash script

Tags: regex, bash, if-statement, command

I need a bash script to read a file line by line. If a regex match, echo this line.

The script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Start!"

for line in $(cat results)
do
   regex = '^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+$'
   if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
   then
      echo $line
   fi
done
```

It is printing the file content, but show this warning:

```
./script: line 7: regex: command not found
```

Where is the error?

Comment: What you have posted can be replaced by `grep '^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+$' results`.

Comment: Subject does not reflect content. This is not a question about reading file line by line but about syntax of bash assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in this case is the spaces around the `=` sign in `regex = '^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+$'`

It should be

```
regex='^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+$'
```

[ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) automatically warns you about this, and also suggests where to quote your variables and how to read line by line (you're currently doing it word by word).

Answer (score 8):

Others have given you hints about the actual regexp to use.
The *proper* way to loop over all the lines in a file is this:

```
#!/bin/bash

regex='[0-9]'

while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done < input
```

Answer (score 1):

Elimnate the spaces around regex:

```
regex='^[0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+$'
```